# Event thread in java

Tags: java, events, multithreading

I want to create a background Thread handling some tasks (Runnable) and executing them in the order in which they are posted.

Important : these tasks must NOT be executed on the Event Dispatcher Thread.

Something like :

```
BackgroundEventThread backgroundEventThread  = new BackgroundEventThread();
```

then, later, and in many places in the code:

```
Runnable thingToDo = new Runnable(){...};

backgroundEventThread.executeThis(thingToDo);
//the things to do will be executed in the order in which they are posted.
```

The class `BackgroundEventThread` should be quite straightforward to code, but I was wondering if such a class already existed in some place unknown to me in the JDK or in some common library...

**EDIT** : I don't know in advance the number of tasks to execute on this thread.

I could have:

- task0 (really short) happening at t0
- task1 (long to process...) happening 
  at t0+1s
- task2 (short) happening at t0+5s etc.
- task3 (etc, etc...)

And I need task2 (that I don't know in advance) to be executed after task1, and I want all these tasks to be executed asap.

Exactly like tasks posted on the EDT, but NOT on the EDT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

You can set this up with a "pool" of a single thread, and then throw tasks at it to execute for you.

Comment: btw, SwingWorker uses exactly ThreadPoolExecutor internally. Only it has a constant defining the max threads.

Answer (score 2):

Check [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

> An abstract class to perform lengthy GUI-interacting tasks in a dedicated thread.

All the necessary details as of how to use it are in the javadoc.

Comment: Does `SwingWorker` guarantee execution order?

Comment: It is not exactly what I'm looking for:

- I don't need any interaction with the EDT

- My tasks are short, and there are many of them, that can be created any time. So I would need many swing workers, and I cant be sure that all of them will share the same background thread.

Comment: it's asynchronous, hence no execution order (if I get your question correctly). If you want two subsequent operations in the background, use one swing worker with two helper classes which execute each of the sequential tasks.
Additionally, I think you can control the number of async threads via ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: I see a contradiction with this requirement: "Important : these tasks must NOT be executed on the Event Dispatcher Thread."

Comment: Carl, what do you mean? a contradiction between SwingWorker and the requirement, or a contradiction withing the requirement itself?

Comment: @Carl Smotricz : Because on the swing EventDispatcherThread they would freeze the GUI. And these are background tasks.

Comment: @Carl, SwingWorker uses ThreadPoolExecutor internally to do the job, so I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: From SwingWorker's doc, it's apparently used "to perform lengthy GUI-interacting tasks in a dedicated task". But there's no requirement for GUI interaction, and specifically a requirement not to run this stuff on the EDT.

Comment: Yep, I see that. But if there's no requirement for notifying the EDT, why bother using the specialized class?

Comment: Yes, for a simple task it might be oversized. But it is not contradicting the requirement.
I'd still use SwingWorker in this situation, because in the future I might need the additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to configure an [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to do exactly what you need.